# How to get the username of the last svn commit using ant?

Tags: svn, ant

I would like to use Ant to get the username of the latest commit of a svn repository.

how can i do this as cross-platform as possible?

thanks!

Comment: The info is inside `.svn/entries` of the project root

Comment: @okm: in this file there is only a number. is this some kind of index?

Comment: @ clamp: have you tried any of http://code.google.com/p/svntask/  or http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant.html. First one has svn log command implemented.

Comment: @clamp: Both tools have problem with SVN 1.7. I place my bet on "svnant" (project more organized).

Comment: @all in the end i went with a pure svnkit solution. i dont know who to award the bounty now.

Comment: @clamp: `pure svnkit solution` - you mean like on [this page](http://svnkit.com/kb/user-guide-ant.html)?

Comment: @Vadim: yes pretty much like this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, here is example for "svnant":

```
<path id="devlibs.path">
    <fileset dir="devlib" includes="**/*.jar" />
</path>

<typedef resource="org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml" classpathref="devlibs.path" />

<svnSetting
        id="svn.settings"
        svnkit="false"
        javahl="false"
        username="${svn.username}"
        password="${svn.password}" />

<target name="get-svn-author">
    <svn refid="svn.settings">
        <singleinfo target="${svn.repo.url}" property="author.result" request="author" />
    </svn>

    <echo message="Author of last commit: ${author.result}" />
</target>
```

You should put "svnant.jar" and "svnClientAdapter.jar" to path identified by "devlibs.path". And other libraries required by "javahl" or "svnkit" to your "${ANT_HOME}/lib".

If you have SVN repository with 1.6 format, you could use "svnkit" (set to "true" in "svnSetting"-block). Because "svnkit" is a pure Java-toolkit it's best to use when you need cross-platform solution. If you already switched to 1.7, then I recommend to use SVN command line client ("svnSetting" configured for command line client in my example). Check [this page](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download/) (Slik SVN) for info about where to find and how to install different SVN command line clients.

Comment: This answer is also a good example of how to use SvnAnt's svnSetting since the parameters username, password, javahl, svnkit, etc. are now  deprecated for the [svn](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant/svntask.html) task.

Answer (score 7):

Just in case you prefer a solution that does not use optional tasks, here's the gist of how you can do it:

```
<target name="get-svn-author">
    <tempfile property="svninfo.result"/>
    <exec executable="svn" output="${svninfo.result}">
        <arg value="info"/>
        <arg value="${svn.repo.url}"/>
    </exec>
    <tempfile property="svnauthor.result"/>
    <copy file="${svninfo.result}" tofile="${svnauthor.result}">
        <filterchain>
            <linecontainsregexp>
                <regexp pattern="Last Changed Author:*"/>
            </linecontainsregexp>
        </filterchain>
    </copy>
    <concat>
        <filelist files="${svnauthor.result}"/>
    </concat>
    <delete file="${svninfo.result}"/>
    <delete file="${svnauthor.result}"/>
</target>
```

One catch is that you write/delete files which may not always be possible (i.e. if you do not have permissions). Another catch is that an svn client (that can be run via `svn` command from the command line) must be installed.

Comment: not related to your answer but can a `filset` dir= be linked to svn repository not to local folder ? for example in this <fileset id="matches" dir="localdir..">  i want the dir to be on svn server is that possible

Answer (score 1):

I thought I had posted an answer. This is more or less malenkiy_scot's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10166690/368630). However, I use the `--xml` flag on the `svn info` command. This put the output of the `svn info` command in xml output. I was then able to use the `<xmlproperty>` task to read it.

By using resource collections, I also avoided the problem of saving the output into a file which has to be deleted later on.

```
<project>
    <property name="svn.url" value="http://svn.foo.com/src/repos"/>
    <exec executable="svn"
        outputproperty="svn.info">
        <arg value="info"/>
        <arg value="--xml"/>
        <arg value="${svn.url}"/>
    </exec>
    <xmlproperty prefix="svn">
        <propertyresource name="svn.info"/>
    </xmlproperty>
    <echo message="Last committer = ${svn.info.entry.commit.author}"/>
</project>
```

I tried to see if I could get away with using the `<exec>` task itself as a *resource*. That way, I wouldn't even have to save the output of the `svn info` command to a property. But alas, I couldn't figure out how to do that.

---

The most *platform neutral* way is Vadim Ponomarev's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10151619/368630). This was the way I had intended to answer this question.

However, I would have included the svnkit jar file in the `devlib` directory, and forced the use of `svnkit`. This makes sure it works no matter which Subversion client is installed. It will even work even if there is no Subversion client installed. Just keep the required jars inside a directory in the project.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a good solution within a executable shell. That solution has the advantage that you can do it as part of the build phase using scripting and not in the post-build phase.That is explained below. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11837662/5842403

In fact, you can access to the information before the build phase finish by reading/parsing the ../builds/$BUILD_NUMBER/changelog.xml file inside the build folder. This file is created with the SVN commit triggering and not with the end of the build or post_build phase. That means, you can parse it at the start of the build phase of the same job with a script and insert the data in env variables.