# Jenkins: capture git commit message

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, commit-message

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get access to Build Changelog in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823826/get-access-to-build-changelog-in-jenkins)

We have a Jenkins CI server setup that is doing rubymotion testflight builds. Rubymotion allows a message to be sent to testflight as 'notes' on that build. We are interested in capturing the git commit message and passing it along to the rake testflight task.

Is there a Jenkins plugin that could capture the commit message in a global variable?

Comment: There's no plugin, but this question is answered here: [Get access to Build Changelog in Jenkins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823826/get-access-to-build-changelog-in-jenkins).