# Passing $CHANGES, $CONSOLE in downstream Jenkins jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to pass $CHANGES from my upstream project to downstream project.

- I looked at [How to pass ${CHANGES} to downstream job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576251/how-to-pass-changes-to-downstream-job) which did not work for me. The All Changes Plugin does *not* put the changes in environment variable so I can't access them in the downstream job (or maybe I don't know the correct env. variable it uses)
- The method to get changes from Parent Job URL and parse the XML also does not work, because it would be hard to correlate the parent job number which triggered this downstream build.

Is there something else that I can try?

Comment: Are you use "Trigger" method for your downstream jobs or something else?

Comment: Hi @Slav Paramterized build trigger plugin is what I'm using right now

Answer (score 0):

The Parameterized Trigger plugin allows you to pass variables to downstream job.

- Click **"Add Parameters"** dropdown under "Trigger parameterized build"
- Select **"Predefined Parameter"**
- Type `CHANGES=${CHANGES}`

The left side of `=` is the variable that will be injected into the child job.
The right side of `=` is the value from the current build.

Provided that you have `${CHANGES}` as an environment variable in the current build, it will pass the same into the child build. You can change the left-side variable name to avoid any conflicts.

**Note:** Since version 2.23 of the plugin, the left side variable **has to exist as a parameter** in the child job. You need to define an empty "Text" parameter called `CHANGES` (or whatever your left side name is) in the child job configuration.

Comment: $CHANGES does not exist as an environment parameter. It is althought available inside Email-Ext-Plugin as a parameter and lists the changes, but does not exists as an environment parameter.