# Saving Jenkins changelog from TFS to file

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I want to save a text file with all check-in messages from TFS, and save it as a build artifact.

Simply put, I want to save changelog.xml or something similar as build artifact. Is it something simple to do? Currently I run a post-build batch script and do it myself, but there must be a simpler way.

Comment: If you can figure out how to display a list of TFS changes from command line, then piping it to file and saving as build artifact is easy and I can help with that. I don't know anything about TFS though, so you have to find out that part first

Comment: @Slav It works for now but ugly. And I don't want to invest effort in parsing the detailed command-line output myself. It would be much much easier if I could just take the nice html Jenkins creates.

Answer (score 0):

This answer has instructions on how to get Jenkins's own SCM change log into an XML file
[Get access to Build Changelog in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823826/get-access-to-build-changelog-in-jenkins)

After that, you need to include that .xml as part of your **Build Artifacts** to archive

Alternatively, the actual changelog.xml is saved on Jenkins's filesystem, under `$JENKINS_HOME/jobs/<job_name>/builds/<build_timestamp>/changelog.xml`. You can write a clever script that will look at that location for the latest timestamp and pull that file into your workspace and then archive it