# Jenkins change log

Tags: shell, jenkins, accurev

I am trying to get chage log from Jenkins from last successful build from Accurev and I am using accurev hist command with this I am getting only latest history. is there any way to find out list of all change log. thank in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823826/get-access-to-build-changelog-in-jenkins

Answer (score 0):

Install the AccuRev plugin for Jenkins.